# Can と be used with verbs other than 思う to imply a thought process behind the action?

Tags: word-choice, verbs, particle-と

Following hot on the heels on my other question about [`と` and `思う`](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/3065/can-and-be-interchanged-with-the-way-i-think-they-can), I know `と` can be used with `言う`, but can it also be applied to verbs that imply some kind of thinking process other than `思う`?

Do these make grammatical sense?

あそこに行くと決めた【あそこに　いくと　きめた】 (I decided, "I'll go over there")

あそこに行くと考えた【あそこに　いくと　かんがえた】 (I considered, "I'll go over there")

あそこに行くと感じた【あそこに　いくと　かんじた】 (I felt, "I'll go over there")

If so, are there other verbs that might take と to imply a thought process behind the action?

Comment: the と in 行くと sounds more like the "if you do X, then Y" pattern to me. E.g. 行くと分かる = If you go, then you'll understand. I think you need to change the verb into volitional form (行こうと). Or another way is to replace と with こと+に (行くことに決めた) ..

Comment: と+決めた／考えた etc. can definitely be used (と分かった is another big one). As Lukman points out, there could be issues of ambiguities, particularly when the subject to both propositions is the same. But sentences like "私は寒いと感じた" or "私はその箱が空だと分かった" are perfectly fine...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> but can it also be applied to verbs that imply some kind of thinking process other than 思う?

Yes, all of them, I think.

> Do these make grammatical sense?

Yes.  But I wonder how to say the third one.  The translation is weird…
With 感じる、 I think that a better example is

```
もう死んでいたと感じた
```

I felt that he was already dead (say, by touching him)

> If so, are there other verbs that might take と to imply a thought process behind the action?

Yes, as I said earlier.

```
 旅行しようと検討してる。  
 早く寝ないとと思いだした。 (yes, double と)  
 彼はアホだと分かった。
```

and many others I guess.