# Does this sentence have a good or bad meaning?

Tags: meaning

> あたしのお母さんはあなたはなぜあたしを好きか不思議らしい

I know that 不思議 can mean either marvelous or strange so I'm a bit confused to really understand the meaning of this sentence which came on its own without a context.

Comment: You should at least explain the parts you do understand, otherwise the question is likely to be closed as a pure 'translation' question.

Comment: This is very bad obviously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

不思議 in this context means 不思議に思う, 疑問に思う, 'wonder', etc.

> あたしのお母さんは[あなたはなぜあたしを好きか]不思議らしい
>   It seems that my mom is wondering [why you like me].
>   (brackets used to emphasize the grammatical structure)

This can be a good news if the mother is just thinking the male person is disproportionately nice for her daughter. Depending on the context, this also can be a bad news if the mother wants them to break up.

Comment: In case someone felt あたしを好き is odd, see [this](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/4210/5010) and [this](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/3473/5010).