# How to say: Mary thinks that Robert likes Tom

Tags: translation

How would you say: "Mary thinks that Robert likes Tom." ?

My guess would be メアリーさんはロバートさんはトムさんが好きだと思っている。

I'm just not sure if there should be a は or a が after ロバートさん because there is already a topic は particle reserved for メアリーさん.

Comment: These might help: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/4210/why-is-を-used-in-this-situation-私は先生がネコを好きだと思います and https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/3473/を-vs-が-with-use-against-好き/3474#3474

Comment: Thank you @Nanigashi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be a は after ロバートさん because you are actually quoting what Mary is saying, so like メアリーさんは「ロパートさんはトムさんが好きだ」と思っている